# Will FG ground os SMPS be effective for ringing wave?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, grounding

In our factory, ATMEGA AVR(MCU) is used to control production control.
There were some malfunctions, so. I checked the MCU power line(5VDC).
I found a big ringing waves, peak 13.5V.

SMPS is not grounded now.
Input power is isolated by external small isolation TR.
Will the ringing waves be reduced if i ground SMPS?
(MSF15-05 fine suntronics)

But. I worry about the ground loop.
CPU board's IOs are gavanic isolated.

And i will put some ferrite core as a bead.

Do i have to ground SMPS?

[image: ringing wave]

[image: MSF15-05 fine suntronics]

[image: ringing wave]

Comment: your oscilloscope is grounded so if you're measuring a floating signal, then it is not unusual you are seeing transient signals. You need to show us a schematic of the system as we can't see what you are seeing.

Comment: My comment will be the same as to your previous identical question: Post a schematic of the power supply circuit and indicate how you probe it. Otherwise it will be wild guesswork.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Osilloscope is isolated by isolation noise cut transformer. Wave from is probed at SMPS output terminal(5vdc, 0v)